# How can I change text color under Doughnut chart in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, next.js, charts, react-chartjs-2

I am using the Doughnut from the react-chartjs-2 library and I would like to change the color only of the writings under the graph, I would like to put them in white since with this background they cannot be read very well (Look at the photo).
Could anyone tell me how I can do it?

[image: Screenshot of my chart]

Thanks in advance,
Fabio Tamburini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add few things into the options props of your **Doughnut** chart as bellow:

```js
const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

For more details, please visit docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)